# Getting junit output from node-qunit?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, qunit

I have the following test runner for my node.js application's unit tests using the node wrapper for qunit:

```
var testrunner = require("qunit");
testrunner.run({
    code: "./lib/application.js",
    tests: ["./lib/test1.js","./lib/test2.js"]
}, function(){
});
```

This outputs a pretty human-readable report of my unit tests. All seems to be working as planned.

How do I modify the above file to make it output JUnit format? I've been trying to integrate [qunit-reporter-junit](https://github.com/jquery/qunit-reporter-junit) but everything I try results in errors. Where do I put the code to override `QUnit.jUnitReport` such that the `QUnit` object is in scope?